# Bookmarks in SSRS that working when rendered to PDF

Tags: pdf, reporting-services

I'm trying to create a report in SSRS where you can click on text to send you to a specific page. It would need to work just like the Bookmarks function inside of SSRS. The problem is that Bookmarks are not supported once the report is rendered to PDF. I want to have the same functionally as Bookmarks, and using a Document Map is not an expectable alternative according to the specs of the project.

Does anyone know of a way to get the same functionality as Bookmarks, in a PDF rendered report?

Comment: I don't have time to check right now, but I'm pretty sure bookmarks do work when rendered to PDF. I think you still set document map properties but you don;t need to use the document map to navigate round the document. I'll check later if I get time.

Comment: They show up as bookmarks in PDF, but do not behave like bookmarks do in SSRS. The goal would be to have a text box that shows "Back", that is bookmarked to the summary page in the report. I can accomplish it in SSRS, but when it is rendered to PDF it doesn't work. Per Microsoft, it isn't supported. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-builder/exporting-to-a-pdf-file-report-builder-and-ssrs  I am looking for a way to accomplish the same task.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I have the same exact problem. I have a tablix, with a textbox for each "section". Each section is a tablix that follows the TOC talbix.  I gave each "section" tablix a bookmark name and set the corresponding TOC texbox action to that bookmark. I also did the document map, but I want the TOC tablix to be clickable, after the SSRS report is rendered to PDF. I would love a solution to this challenge!

Comment: No answer as of yet.